# Dropdownchecklist not showing selection in internet explorer after re-initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

After an ajax post I destroy and then re- initialize a dropdownchecklist so that I may re-populate the list. In chrome/firefox this works as expected. In Internet explorer however the selected items do not appear in the comma delimited form in the text-box section, instead the text display just remains empty.

```
$distList.dropdownchecklist("destroy");
$distList.html(items);
$($distList, $container).dropdownchecklist({
                        icon: { placement: 'right', toOpen: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s', toClose: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-n' },                    
                       firstItemChecksAll: true, 
                       width: 151, 
                       maxDropHeight: 150, 
                       onComplete: function () {
                        }
                    });
```

**EDIT**

The following [Link](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) will show why I use destroy and initialize. It discusses the refresh only works on changed selected, not adding/chanigng the list itself.'

**DISCOVERY**

After messing around in the IE debugger I have discovered turning off display: inline-block removes the problem, but can't figure out how to replicate that effect in code.

Comment: Good question - 8 & 11 for sure. While I'm at it - Jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in a `setTimeout`

```
$distList.dropdownchecklist("destroy");
$distList.html(items);
function doList() {
    $($distList, $container).dropdownchecklist({
        icon: { placement: 'right', toOpen: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s', toClose: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-n' },                    
        firstItemChecksAll: true, 
        width: 151, 
        maxDropHeight: 150, 
        onComplete: function () {}
    }); 
}

setTimeout(doList, 50);
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately.